# Playing a video in JWPlayer through a video link in Drupal 7

Tags: php, video, drupal-7, jwplayer

Usually I have a video file field where I upload the video and configure display to be open with JWPlayer. It then opens as JWPlayer when I output it in the template (node.tpl.php)

But now the problem is that in some cases, I'll get a link like

```
http://www.mytest.com/videos/myvideo.mp4
```

which I want to play in JWPlayer too. Is it possible that I can play a video link directly in JWPlayer?

Thanks.

Comment: Just use that link as the JW Player's file variable and it should work fine.